# Android Google Maps API application crashing on startup

Tags: android, eclipse, maps

I am new to Android programming. I learnt the very basics of an Activity and Activity Life cycle, and am willing to learn the Google Maps API.

However, I am unable to configure and run an application.I went through the Google documentation on installing the API and did as they said.I even used their code to check if the API was running.But every time I run, my application crashes.I don't know anything about debugging, and logcat shows me a few errors.

Can someone please explain the log to me and also help me get the program running ?I would be really thankful for your help.

Here is what **logcat** shows me(I use Eclipse IDE) **:**

My manifest code:

'

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.geo_tagger"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.geo_tagger.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyA4mPKlxJuy_Wfh-izUee2oY5kokQhB9Z0"/>
</application>

</manifest>' $
```

Comment: post your `manifest.xml` code

Comment: thanks for responding.

Comment: I got the solution.I don't know how it worked but I added an Android Support Library for my application and it worked.I am able to run the application now with no logcat errors.

Thanks for responding to my request,though.